# Filter results via results of another variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to make a contacts manager application as part of my main application and am at the point I need a little advice. I have 2 tables dedicated to managing the contacts.

The first table (Contacts) houses the main info of each contact:
Fields: ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Company

The second table is a lookup assignment table (AssignedContacts) that houses a reference id for the case the contact is to be assigned to and the contact's id:
Fields: ID, ReferenceCaseID, ContactID

Now I am trying to make a view that returns a list of the Contacts assigned to a case. The view will receive the ReferenceCaseID as a parameter.

I am stuck on how to code in the controller to set the variable.

```
public ActionResult Contacts(int id)
    {

        var Contacts = <insert logic to filter contacts to just those assigned based on the parameter passed>

        if (Contacts == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return View(Contacts);
    }
```

I know I can get a list of assigned contacts using the below:

```
var AssignedContacts = _context.AssignedContacts.Where(c => c.ReferenceCaseID == id).ToList();
```

But I am honestly confused on how now take that result and filter the Contacts using this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions on the above as it is hard to explain via text.

Comment: what is `_Context`?  If it's a `DbContext` then your question is relevant to Entity-Framework not asp.net-mvc.

Comment: Question is quite confusing can you provide your Entities classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var contacts = _context.AssignedContacts.Where(ac => ac.ReferenceCaseID == id)
    .Join(_context.Contacts, assigned => assigned.ContactID, contact => contact.ID,        
        (assigned, contact) => contact);
```

I can't test it as I don't have your entire code, but basically, you start with what you did - filter the `AssignedContacts` table.

Then you join the result with the `Contacts` table according to the `ContactID` and `ID` keys from both tables.

Finally, you select contacts of the resulting join.

---

Alternatively, you can join the tables and then filter:

```
var contacts = _context.Contacts.Join(_context.AssignedContacts, contact => 
    contact.ID, assigned => assigned.ContactID, (contact, assigned) => 
        new { Contact = contact, ReferenceCaseID = assigned.ReferenceCaseID } )
    .Where(contactWithRefId => contactWithRefId.ReferenceCaseID == id);
```

Here you start with `Contacts` table and joins it with the `AssignedContacts` table according to the `ID` and `ContactID` keys from both tables.

Then you create a new kind of anonymous object which is a contact with a `ReferenceCaseID` (this means you might have duplicate contacts with different `ReferenceCaseID`).

Finally, you use the `where` to filter these new contact objects by the `ReferenceCaseID` which will remove all the irrelevant contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join on the contact id between the two entities, Assigned Contacts and Contacts, then filter where the reference id is what you passed in.

Untested for your situation, but may get you started:

```
var contactsMatching= (from c in dbContext.Contacts 
                 join ac in dbContext.AssignedContacts on 
                 c.ID equlas ac.ContactID
                 where ac.ReferenceCaseID==<your provided id>
                  select Contact{
                     ID = c.ID,
                     FirstName= c.FirstName,
                     ..snip..
                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their answers above. I got with one of my buddies at work and found what I was looking for using the below:

```
public ActionResult Contacts(int id)
    {

        var Contacts =
                from contact in _context.Contacts
                join assignedcontact in _context.AssignedContacts on contact.Id equals assignedcontact.ContactId
                where assignedcontact.ReferenceCaseID == id
                select contact;

        if (Contacts == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return View(Contacts);
    }
```